# Iterating through a two dimensional array in Ruby and substituting a string for every instance

Tags: ruby, arrays

```
  win_array = [ ["TL", "TM", "TR"], ["ML", "MM", "MR"], ["BL", "BM", "BR"], 
    ["TL", "ML", "BL"], ["TM", "MM", "BM"] , ["TR", "MR", "BR"], 
    ["TL", "MM", "BR"], ["TR", "MM", "BL"] ]


  win_array[0].map! {|x| x == "TR" ? "1" : x } #works for [0] array

  win_array[0..7].map! {|x| x == "TR" ? "1" : x } #doesn't work
  win_array.each.map! {|x| x == "TR" ? "1" : x }  #doesn't work
  win_array.each {|x| x.map! == "TR" ? "1" : x }  #doesn't work
```

I am trying to permanently change every instance of "TR" in this 2D array to either an integer or a string. I have tried to use the .map! methods outlined above with little luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to work `win_array.map! { |a| a.map! { |x| x == "TR" ? "1" : x } }`

Comment: Thanks August! I was also wondering why the [0..7].map! doesn't work. Do you know?

Comment: First of all, `Array#[Range]` creates a new `Array` object, so the original `win_array` isn't modified, and secondly, you're mapping over each `Array` in `win_array`, not the elements of that array.

Comment: Awesome. You have been very helpful. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I passed the block you used to change `win_array[0]` (in the first attempt) to a double-nested `map!` call, so it sweeps over each element.

```
win_array.map! { |a| a.map! { |x| x == "TR" ? "1" : x } }
```

Comment: Inplace `map` for nesteds (`a`) is superfluous.

Answer (score 0):

If each row of the array has the same number of elements (as in your example), you could convert the array to a `Matrix` object, apply [Matrix#collect](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html#method-i-collect) (aka `map`), and then convert the matrix back to an array (unless, of course, it is more convenient to keep it as a `Matrix` object for further processing).

```
require 'matrix'

win_array = [ ["TL", "TM", "TR"], ["ML", "MM", "MR"], ["BL", "BM", "BR"], 
              ["TL", "ML", "BL"], ["TM", "MM", "BM"], ["TR", "MR", "BR"], 
              ["TL", "MM", "BR"], ["TR", "MM", "BL"] ]

win_array = Matrix[*win_array].map { |e| (e == "TR") ? "1" : e }.to_a
  #=>       [ ["TL", "TM", "1" ], ["ML", "MM", "MR"], ["BL", "BM", "BR"],
  #           ["TL", "ML", "BL"], ["TM", "MM", "BM"], ["1" , "MR", "BR"],
  #           ["TL", "MM", "BR"], ["1" , "MM", "BL"] ]
```

Answer (score -1):

[Ruby OOP tic-tac-toe hash / conditional / itiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25072697/ruby-oop-tic-tac-toe-hash-conditional-itiration?noredirect=1#comment39008904_25072697)

This may help you, but maybe not lol
We can't figure out how to output our tie function.